# See the number of open windows for an app in the macOS Dock

Tags: macos, catalina, dock

I have multiple Google Chrome windows open at a tune. How can I see the number of open windows in the Dock?

I'd like to add something like a second indicator under the app's Dock icon.

Also, I'd like to be able to choose the window when I click the icon and not use a long click to be able to chose the window to open.

The Dock settings doesn't provide any way to configure this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are asking for.  But better, in my opinion.

I use HyperDock https://bahoom.com/hyperdock/ which shows thumbnails of all windows. It has other features too, which I leave you to explore.  And my preference is the version from the HyperDock web site, not from the App Store.

[image: Two Safari Windows]

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn’t inject code into a running app to provide this count (basically it’s up to the app to manage badges, not the OS). One solution would be to choose apps that have code added to display their window count as a badge (like they do in the window menu and other parts of the app). This is trivial to program as a sample app, but making changes to a large program like Chrome is typically far from trivial. If this feature is important, I think the browser team could make the effort to do it.

Like the mail app counts messages unread and read, it can display arbitrary information in a badge.

Have you seen if this is a feature hidden or made a request to the chrome development team?

- https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/

Although since chrome was created to remove chrome like that, they might see this as more clutter. Hard to guess without engaging them, perhaps.

Comment: Well I don't want to do this only for chrome, I want this for all programs, like if I have multiple terminal windows or editor open. Instead of being a badge it should be the indicator that says the application is running (just below the icon), but there would be multiple indicators if there is multiple windows

Comment: I understand what you want @MickaelB. it’s not how the dock or OS is designed, however. Maybe asking a follow on question as a software recommendation question perhaps someone knows a window manager or utility that has that function.